# Nunjucks nested variables

Tags: html, sql, web, jinja2, nunjucks

Are nested variables possible in Nunjucks? I need to be able to store a string in my database containing Nunjucks variable but it does not seem to work. Here's an example of what I need to be able to do:

```
dict = {
name: 'John',
lastname: 'Smith',
greeting: 'Hello, my name is {{ name }} {{ lastname }}'
}
```

And then be able to do

```
<span>{{greeting}}</span>
```

but it outputs this:

```
'Hello, my name is {{ name }} {{ lastname }}'
```

The reason i need it this way it because I have a database with some description templates with holes and i have a database with values and I need to be able to combine them. But it is not always the same values so I cant hard-code them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is a add `global` or `filter`

```
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();

env.addFilter('render', function(text) {
    return  nunjucks.renderString(text, this.ctx);
});

var res = nunjucks.renderString(
    'name: {{name}}, greeting: {{greeting | render}}', 
    {
        name: 'John',
        greeting: 'Hello {{name}}'
    }
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you! that does the job!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, without additional rendering, if circumstances permit:

```
dict = {
    name: 'John',
    lastname: 'Smith'
}

dict = {
    greeting: 'Hello, my name is ' + dict.name + ' ' + dict.lastname
}
```